# Consolidating two tables in SQL using merge

Tags: sql

I have a problem where I am trying to Merge and consolidate data from one table to another table.

The source and destination tables are identical except the destination needs to have a primary key on the first column.

The data input and desired results are follows:

```
data in        Desired results   
 c1 c2 c3       c1   c2    c3  
+--+--+--+    +--+------+------+  
 1  A  x       1  A B C  x y  
 2  B  z       2  B C    z  
 3  A  z       3  A      z x y   
 1  A  y      +--+------+------+  
 3  A  y   
 1  B  x     
 2  C  z     
 1  C  x     
 3  A  x   
 1  A  x   
+--+--+--+
```

I initialize the tables...

```
CREATE TABLE s (c1 char(2), c2 char(8), C3 char(8))

INSERT INTO s VALUES 
  ('1','A','x'), ('2','B','z'), ('3','A','z'), 
  ('1','A','y'), ('3','A','y'), ('1','B','x'), 
  ('2','C','z'), ('1','C','z'), ('3','A','x'), 
  ('1','A','x')

CREATE TABLE d (c1 char(2) PRIMARY KEY, c2 char(8), C3 char(8))
```

I can get it to work using Cursor...

```
DECLARE @c1 Char(2)
DECLARE @c2 char(8)
DECLARE @C3 char(8)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT c1, c2, C3 FROM s
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @c1, @c2, @C3
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
  UPDATE d SET 
    c2 = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(RTRIM(@c2), c2) > 0 THEN c2 ELSE SUBSTRING(RTRIM(c2) + ' ' + @c2, 1, 8) END),
    c3 = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(RTRIM(@c3), c3) > 0 THEN c3 ELSE SUBSTRING(RTRIM(c3) + ' ' + @c3, 1, 8) END)
    WHERE c1 = @c1
  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO d (c1, c2, c3) 
      VALUES (@c1, @c2, @c3)
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @c1, @c2, @c3
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

But I cannot get Merge to work...
*Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__d__3213663B03BB8E22'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.d'. The duplicate key value is (1 ).*

```
MERGE INTO d USING s 
  ON (s.c1 = d.c1)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
      c2 = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(RTRIM(s.c2), d.c2) > 0 THEN d.c2 ELSE SUBSTRING(RTRIM(d.c2) + ' ' + s.c2, 1, 8) END),
      c3 = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(RTRIM(s.c3), d.c3) > 0 THEN d.c3 ELSE SUBSTRING(RTRIM(d.c3) + ' ' + s.c3, 1, 8) END)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (s.c1, s.c2, s.c3);
```

Is there a way to do this with a little more grace than going row by row?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s - Syntax clearly says it is `sql server`

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid **RBAR** operation using `For XML Path` trick to concatenate the rows of each group.

```
;WITH cte1 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT c1,cs.c2 AS c2 
         FROM   s AS A 
                CROSS apply (SELECT DISTINCT c2 + ' ' 
                             FROM   s AS B 
                             WHERE  A.c1 = B.c1 
                             FOR xml path('')) cs (c2)), 
     cte3 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT c1,cs.c3 AS c3 
         FROM   s AS A 
                CROSS apply (SELECT DISTINCT c3 + ' ' 
                             FROM   s AS B 
                             WHERE  A.c1 = B.c1 
                             FOR xml path('')) cs (c3)) 
SELECT A.c1, 
       a.c2, 
       b.c3 
FROM   cte1 A 
       INNER JOIN cte3 B 
               ON A.c1 = b.c1
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03777/5)

Answer (score 0):

This is best left to the presentation layer,

you can use corelated subquery to concatenate the values of c2, c3 based on the group by c1

you need to use `STUFF` along with `for xml path` to get the concatenated string

```
select c1, stuff( (select distinct ' ' + c2
               from s
               where s.c1 = outs.c1
               for xml path('')), 1,1,''),
           stuff( (select distinct ' ' + c3
               from s
               where s.c1 = outs.c1
               for xml path('')), 1,1,'')
from s outs
group by outs.c1
```